# Using captcha with JAAS - Login Module on Jboss EAP 7

Tags: authentication, jboss7.x, captcha, jaas

I have an application that uses a custom login Module. My module just get the informations of user and password and calls a service.

Now I need to put a captcha in my login screen, but I'm using j_security_check in my form and in my login module i don't know where I can get the information of the captcha challenge.

I tried to use something I got here about PolicyContext, but this approach don't seems to work in my server(Jboss-eap-7).

Any of you have any hint about how captcha works with JAAS and login Module?

Thanks!